# could not get the path on live server symfony 2

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I have write a php code that upload the image to web/uploads/slider which i get through

```
$dir = $this->container->getParameter('assetic.write_to') . '\uploads\slider';
```

In my local server(windows apache) it works fine and upload as expected but the problem comes when i used it in live server it creates a folder name 'web\uploads\slider' in a project folder and upload a file in it

Comment: What problems occur? Please be more specific!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use forward slashes:

```
$dir = $this->container->getParameter('assetic.write_to') . '/uploads/slider';
```

Backslashes only work on Windows OS but forward slashes work on any OS (including Windows).

Comment: exactly the problem is solved. I have used php constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR